# Combining amplitude model and time model into single model for signal processing model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Here are the models for signal processing.

Model A is about processing the amplitude of signal, it will manipulating the amplitude value of signal data, it's about regression task that using regression loss.

Model B is about processing the time of signal, it will manipulating the index of signal data, it's about multi/classsification task that using categorical crossentropy. For example `signal_sample[0]` has class `modelB_label[0]`, `signal_sample[1]` has class `modelB_label[1]`, ...
Note that I'm using label encoding for modelB_label instead of one-hot encoding.

Here is the **reproducible** code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

# Sample data and labels
signal_sample = [101, 102, 105, 106, 107]
modelA_label = [1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
modelB_label = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1] #0: class X, 1:class Y, 2:class Z

# ModelA architecture and compilation
input_layer_modelA = Input(shape=(len(signal_sample),))
hidden_layer_modelA = Dense(16, activation='relu')(input_layer_modelA)
output_modelA = Dense(len(modelA_label), activation='linear')(hidden_layer_modelA)
modelA = Model(inputs=input_layer_modelA, outputs=output_modelA)
modelA.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# ModelB architecture and compilation
input_layer_modelB = Input(shape=(len(modelA_label)))
hidden_layer_modelB = Dense(16, activation='relu')(input_layer_modelB)
output_layer_modelB = Dense(len(modelB_label), activation='softmax')(hidden_layer_modelB)
modelB = Model(inputs=input_layer_modelB, outputs=output_layer_modelB)
modelB.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Display model summaries
modelA.summary()
modelB.summary()
```

How do I combine both models into single model?

I expect combined model accept input shape same as `length of signal_sample`, but I expect the output layer returns predicted of processed amplitudes and predicted classes of every index of signal_sample.

Specifically, the time model input should be inference result (output) of amplitude model. See picture below, 5 means signal size.

[image]